Is there a way to know the container user in mounts section of devcontainer.json?
When creating a devcontainer I mount the local .m2 folder from user home directory on the host. In the specific example it will be mounted to /home/vscode/.m2/ in the container.
    "mounts": [
        "source=${localEnv:HOME}${localEnv:USERPROFILE}/.m2/,target=/home/vscode/.m2/,type=bind,consistency=cached"
    ],

Is there a way to use an environment variable to not be dependent on knowing the username in the container in target parameter?
I know I can control what the container user will be by setting it in devcontainer.json but would like to be able to use the default user.
I've tried varios variants, like ${containerEnv:HOME}, ${containerUser}, ${remoteUser}.
